# Get collection element one by one when needed

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a class Game, which contains a class Board, which contains an ArrayList of Rows.

Currently Game can getCurrentRow() and when the game progresses it does a getNextRow(). Board gets the currentRow, loops over the ArrayList, from the wrong end and at each step holds that row in lastCheckedRow and breaks when it finds currentRow. The nextRow will then become lastCheckedRow. Simple enough, but ugly.

I want to change this approach into streams instead. Is it possible to make a stream that remains reachable, only returning one element at a time when called?

```
public class Board implements Skinnable{

    private Stream<Skinnable> stream;

    protected List<Skinnable> rowItems = new ArrayList<>();

    private BoardRow currentRow;

    private final BoardSkin skin;

    public Board(Game game) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rowItems.add(new BoardRow(game));
            if (i == 9) {
                setCurrentRow((BoardRow) rowItems.get(rowItems.size() - 1));
            }
        }

        stream = rowItems.stream();
        skin = new BoardSkin(this);
    }

    public void setCurrentRow(BoardRow row) {
        currentRow = row;
        currentRow.activate();
    }

    public Row getStreamedRowItem () {

        List<Skinnable> collect = stream.limit(1).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return (Row) collect.get(0);
    }
}
```

This works, one time, then the stream is closed. This is more of a general question. I have searched, both here and other places, but this is too new to me so I can't even phrase my questions correctly and therefor I am stuck.

Comment: All you need is an Iterator, not a Stream. But even then, your code would be much simpler if you just used indexOf() to find the index of the current row, instead of looping by yourself. Or if you stored the **index** of the current row rather than the current row itself (which is what the Iterator will do internally).

Comment: should `getStreamedRowItem` return always the first? Or work the load of like a queue?

Comment: @Lino It starts with the first right now when testing, but I intend to start from the end, or I will flipp the inserting of the rows and start from the beginning.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, an index would have worked fine, and I started with that. Trying to use newer things to practice, so I changed it to using the entire object in hopes of "streaming" "lazily"  after read some about getting entries of infinite streams with producers and consumers and thought that that was what I needed. You guys have made me realize I was confused about the process though and ernest_k's code example helped me implementing an Iterator instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams can be traversed only once. So you cannot keep it open and yet run the `.collect` terminal operation.

The best alternative for retrieving an element at a time is to use an iterator:

```
private Iterator<Skinnable> stream; //Please rename the variable
```

Then create the iterator in the constructor with:

```
stream = rowItems.iterator();
```

Retrieving the next element changes to:

```
public Row getStreamedRowItem () {

    //you'll need to check if there's a next element
    //if(stream.hasNext())
    return stream.next();
}
```

Comment: So I was searching in the wrong direction. Thanks alot for helping me with some code, already got it working. Needed to refactor some, as its hard to return a Row when next() says that there aint no more.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would follow JB Nizet's idea which will give you more space/chance to control.

Since you already had `rowItems`, just by adding another `index` you can fly anywhere you want in the `collection`.

Have something as:

```
int index; // always pointing to the element to be fetched;

public Board(Game game) { {
    index = 0; // pointing to the first element;
    // or if you want it to point to the last using rowItems.size() - 1 instead;

}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return index < rowItems.size();
}

public Row next() {
    return (Row) rowItems.get(index++);
}

public boolean hasPrevious() {
    return index > -1;
}

public Row previous() {
    return (Row) rowItems.get(index--);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't next() and previous() return the same Row since the increment/decrement is after the variable? ++index and --index instead?
I like the approach, it lets me use the rowItems in the way I thought the streams would. Thanks.

Comment: @JohanLarsson Actually as you mentioned, you can adjust it to meet your needs:) but you have to be careful with the checking method to keep the related checking valid all the times. Also you should understand hasX() working with X() altogether.